# Array Data Changes Outside of Function

Tags: python, arrays

I'm writing a function to take purchases of a yearly software license & return the amount of money that that was spent in each month. So putting in.

```
#[company id, user id, purchase amount, date in yy-mm format, day when customer first registered]
['55463', '114769', $200, '14-5', '2/14/2013']
```

Would return

```
['55463', '114769', $17.5, '14-5', '2/14/2013']
['55463', '114769', $17.5, '14-6', '2/14/2013']
['55463', '114769', $17.5, '14-7', '2/14/2013']
['55463', '114769', $17.5, '14-8', '2/14/2013']
```

etc. I've got a function that prints out this as desired. However, when I try to access the data outside the function, the array that I had written into suddenly only shows last month repeated a number of times. So the last example would have been.

```
['55463', '114769', $17.5, '14-8', '2/14/2013']
['55463', '114769', $17.5, '14-8', '2/14/2013']
['55463', '114769', $17.5, '14-8', '2/14/2013']
['55463', '114769', $17.5, '14-8', '2/14/2013']
```

I can't figure this out for the life of me & would very much appreciate any help. Here is my code. I believe the error to be somewhere in the for loop that begins for x in range(11). Thank you for your help!

```
line_items = []
annualized = []
def csv_dict_reader(file_obj):
global board_info 
reader = csv.DictReader(file_obj, delimiter=',')
for line in reader:
    item = []
    item.append(line["company id"])
    item.append(line["user id"])
    item.append(line["Amount"])
    item.append(line["Transaction Date"])
    item.append(line["FIrst Transaction"])
    line_items.append(item)
if __name__ == "__main__":
with open("ChurnTest.csv") as f_obj:
    csv_dict_reader(f_obj)

def dateSplit():
for i in range(1,4192):
    line = line_items[i]
    amount = line_items[i][2]
    if len(amount) > 1 and line_items[i][1] == '114769':
        if float(amount) > 150:
                line_items[i][2] = float(amount) / 12
                #monthly_transactions.append(line_items[i])
                year = int(line[3][:2])
                month = int(line[3][4:])
                for x in range(11):
                    month = int(month)            
                    year = int(year)
                    newLine = line_items[i]
                    if month > 11:
                        year = year + 1
                        month = 1
                    else:
                        month = month + 1
                    newLine[3] = str(year) + "-" + str(month)
                    annualized.append(newLine)
                    #This prints out the data as I want it to be
                    print(annualized[len(annualized)-1])
        else:
            monthly_transactions.append(line_items[i])

dateSplit()
#This prints out the data incorrectly.
print(annualized)
```

Comment: Please use correct indentation. It is very important for Python.

Comment: Also, could you reduce this to a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and provide a sample of data we can actually run?

Comment: Pro Tip: `annualized[-1]` is equivalent to `annualized[len(annualized)-1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right about the source of the error, it's in the loop `for x in range(11):`. This line:

```
 newLine = line_items[i]
```

**doesn't** create a new object. Python lists are mutable, so even after you edit it `newLine` still refers to the *same object* that's in `annualized` And `line_items`. The minimal fix is:

```
newLine = line_items[i][:] # or 'line[:]' - see below
```

which makes `newLine` a separate copy on each loop.

You should probably read [this](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) and [this](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables) for more on names and references.

Why assign `line` then keep referring to `line_items[i]`? Also, it seems really odd to hard code `4192`; could you not do `for line in line_items[1:]:`?

Comment: Awesome, thank you for your help! And yes,I agree that hardcoding it at 4192 is a super inelegant solution. I was importing for a csv & there was a blank line at the end that kept working its way into the file. Since I only need to do this for this one thing I just changed it, although I should definitely fix it.